# LINQ and Grouping by Week

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a string field which contains a date which I cast as date. I need to group it using LINQ by week. My eventual goal is to have it as

YEAR
WEEK
BeginDateOfWeek (week starts on Monday)

BeginDateOfWeek would actually be used in the reports. Year and week are there to feed a function (not written yet but will be once I figure this out) which would determine the date information in BeginDateOfWeek.

However when I group by this date field as YEAR and WEEK with both functions called i I get:

YEAR=2020, WEEK= generated method

I did a for each and sure enough every week is listed as WEEK=generated method.

So I tried renaming the function (just spitballing on what is happening so I tried that) in the join clause to j and I get the error:

> "Error    BC36621 'Equals' cannot compare a value of type 'Function (i As Object) As Integer' with a value of type 'Function (j As Object) As Integer'."

So if anyone could help I would be so grateful. This is vb.net (c# solutions are fine) and NOT Linq To Entites but regular LINQ. I am really at wits end.

```vb
Dim query = From CCM In tbl1 Group CCM _
            By Year = CType(CCM.LCDATE, Date).Year,
            Week = (Function(i) System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(i.LCDATE, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)) Into grp = Group
            Group Join CCT In (From CCTS In tbl2
                               Group CCTS _
                               By Year1 = CType(CCTS.CCDATE, Date).Year, Week1 = (Function(j) System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(j.CCDATE, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday))
                               Into grp1 = Group) 
            On Year Equals CCT.Year1 And Week Equals CCT.Week1
            Into Merged = Group From CCT In Merged.DefaultIfEmpty()
            Select New With {.YEAR = Year, .WEEK = Week, .MyTest = "")}
```

Comment: can you delete ``c#`` tag

Comment: sure but I said C# solutions are welcome. Client wants vb.net. But I will do it.

Comment: I will try this @jdweng

Comment: @djv Marked as answers. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error says,

```
(Function(i) System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(i.LCDATE, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday))
```

and its counterpart are functions.

You need to actually execute those functions:

```
(Function(i) System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(i.LCDATE, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday))(CType(CCM.LCDATE, Date))
```

Or, preferably, define that function elsewhere and then use it in your query:

```
Function getWeekOfYear (str As String) As Integer

    Return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
        CType(str, Date), 
        System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday
    )

End Function


Dim query = 
    From CCM In tbl1 
    Group CCM By 
        Year = CType(CCM.LCDATE, Date).Year,
        Week = getWeekOfYear(CCM.LCDATE) Into grp = Group
        Group Join CCT In (
            From CCTS In tbl2
            Group CCTS By 
                Year1 = CType(CCTS.CCDATE, Date).Year, 
                Week1 = getWeekOfYear(CCTS.CCDATE)
                Into grp1 = Group
        ) 
        On Year Equals CCT.Year1 And Week Equals CCT.Week1
        Into Merged = Group 
    From CCT In Merged.DefaultIfEmpty()
    Select New With {.YEAR = Year, .WEEK = Week, .MyTest = ""}
```

Comment: No I don't but I wish I did. The solution was so obvious and I lost a whole day over it. But I made it more complicated then necessary as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I tested following code which starts on first Monday of the Year.

```
       Dim Year As Integer = 2020
        Dim jan1 As New DateTime(Year, 1, 1)
        Dim firstMonday As DateTime = jan1.AddDays((8 - jan1.DayOfWeek) Mod 7)
        Dim firstMondayDayOfYear As Integer = firstMonday.DayOfYear

        Dim days As List(Of DateTime) = Enumerable.Range(0, 365).Select(Function(x) firstMonday.AddDays(x)).ToList()
        Dim weeks = days.GroupBy(Function(x) CType((x.DayOfYear - firstMondayDayOfYear) / 7, Integer)).ToList()
```

---

I would create a function which can be called inside a linq

```
    Function GetWeek(day As DateTime) As Integer
        Dim Year As Integer = day.Year
        Dim jan1 As New DateTime(Year, 1, 1)
        Dim firstMonday As DateTime = jan1.AddDays((8 - jan1.DayOfWeek) Mod 7)
        Dim firstMondayDayOfYear As Integer = firstMonday.DayOfYear

        Dim week = CType((day.DayOfYear - firstMondayDayOfYear) / 7, Integer)
        Return week
    End Function
```

Comment: can you show how that would be used in my LINQ query please?

Comment: You can call a function from a linq.  I updated the code to make it a single function.